# Configuring multiple SAML2 instances in IdentityServer3 using SustainSys

Tags: identityserver3, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

In IdentityServer3 I have configured multiple instances of SAML2 based external providers using [SustainSys](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) library as per the [documentation](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/identity-server-3-okta.html#step-6-enable-multiple-okta-instances-multi-tenant-multiple-independent-okta-idps).
I got it working, but i have question about `SPOptions.EntityID` aka `Audience Uri`. *(This is NOT the EntityID that external provider give us, but instead it's the EntityID that i need to provide to external provider)*

Should this `Audience Uri` be unique for each instance?

Lets say, i configured 2 instances of SAML2 providers(Okta and Azure AD) in production, then based on the sample [code](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/identity-server-3-okta.html#configure-a-new-instance-of-saml2-middleware-within-idsrv3) provided, for particular environment the `Audience Uri`will NOT be unique.

Below is my code based on sample code. *(For brevity i have removed few lines)*

```
public class Startup
{        
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
            {                    
                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
                {         
                    EnableAutoCallbackForFederatedSignout = true,
                    EnableSignOutPrompt = false
                }
                .Configure(ConfigureExternalIdentityProviders)                    
            };
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions);
        });            
    }

    private void ConfigureExternalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {           
        // Add okta
        AddSAML2Idp(
            app,                
            signInAsType,
            "https://id.mydomain.com/identity/Saml2", //audienceURI
            "okta", //idpname
            "okta", //caption
            "https://www.okta.com/exk4yxtgy7ZzSDp8e0h7", // externalEntityID
            "https://dev-490944.oktapreview.com/app/exk4yxtgy7ZzSDp8e0h7/sso/saml/metadata"); // metadataLocation

        // Add Azure AD
        AddSAML2Idp(app,                
            signInAsType,
            "https://id.mydomain.com/identity/Saml2", //audienceURI
            "azuread", //idpname
            "Azure ad", //caption
            "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx-fb1d-40c4-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx/", //externalEntityID
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-fb1d-40c4-40c4-xxxxxxx/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"); //metadataLocation
    }      

    private void AddSAML2Idp(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType,string audienceURI, string idpname, string caption, string externalEntityID, string metadataLocation)
    {
        var authenticationOptions = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
        {
            SPOptions = new SPOptions
            {
                EntityId = new EntityId(audienceURI),                     
                ModulePath = string.Format("/{0}", idpname)
            },
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
            AuthenticationType = idpname,
            Caption = caption
        };

        UseIdSrv3LogoutOnFederatedLogout(app, authenticationOptions);

        authenticationOptions.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(LoadCertificateFromWindwosStore());

        var identityProvider = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(externalEntityID), authenticationOptions.SPOptions)
        {                
            MetadataLocation = metadataLocation,
            LoadMetadata = true 
        };

        authenticationOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(identityProvider);

        app.UseSaml2Authentication(authenticationOptions);
    }
```

So for `okata`

```
Audience Uri: https://id.mydomain.com/identity/Saml2
ACS Uri: https://id.mydomain.com/identity/okta/acs
```

and for `Azure AD`

```
Audience Uri: https://id.mydomain.com/identity/Saml2
ACS Uri: https://id.mydomain.com/identity/azuread/acs
```

Note the audience uri is same for both instances.

Should it be unique for each instances like:

```
https://id.mydomain.com/identity/okta   
https://id.mydomain.com/identity/azuread
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically the two instances are two different SAML2 Service Providers and should have different Entity IDs. But, as you're not exposing both of them to the same upstream Idp it doesn't matter.

Comment: But what if i configured two instances of `Azure AD` owned by 2 different clients. So basically they will have two different metadata locations? Should Audience Uri be different is such case? Also 2nd question Is it valid to use `Guid` as idpname?